# Why is the "Battery Health..." button missing in my Big Sur System Preferences?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, big-sur

I'm trying to determine the battery health on an old MacBook Pro. Specs are: *A1398 MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)*, Model Identifier *MacBookPro11,3*, running *macOS 11.5.2* (Big Sur).

According to [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/check-the-condition-of-your-computers-battery-mh20865/11.0/mac/11.0) (note that the OS selector is correctly set to Big Sur), I can do that by going to: `Apple menu > System Preferences > [Battery icon] > [Battery icon]`, at which point I'm supposed to see a button entitled `Battery Health...`, and I'm to click that. The image below (from this [Tom's Guide article](https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-check-macbook-battery-health)) shows what I *should* see:

[image]

But I don't. I see the following:

[image]

As you can see, it is very similar to the previous one, but a major difference is that the `Battery Health...` button simply isn't there.

Any ideas why I'm seeing something different from what Apple says I should?
And, more to the point, any ideas how I might determine my battery health?

Answer (score 1):

The `Battery Health...` button requires hardware support as well as being provided in macOS software. Older MacBooks do not have the hardware capability.

For example, my MacBook 2016 with macOS 12 does not show Battery Health and does not support Optimised Charging.

But you can find out about the battery health. The app [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) does this. As well as showing current battery health it will keep a history for you.

I am taking 'battery health' as the maximum charge capacity of battery now compared with nominal value when new.  Typically this will decline from 100% (or even a bit more) when new to around 80% when you should be considering a battery replacement.

Edit (added, with thanks, from @AVelj's comment):

For alternative ways of getting battery health/condition, you can access this information from `System Profiler`>`Hardware`>`Power` and it should tell you what is the maximum charge of your MacBook. You could also run the command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` in terminal to obtain this information.

Comment: Essentially what @Gilby has said above. Note, if you are just looking at your battery's condition, you can access this information from `System Profiler`>`Hardware`>`Power` and it should tell you what is the maximum charge of your MacBook. You could also run the command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` in terminal to obtain this information instead of from System Profiler app. Also note, none of this will allow you to optimise your battery usage/charging as this feature is only available for more recent MacBook models

Comment: @AVelj I have taken the liberty of adding your comment into my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yep all good @Gilby. That's fine.

Comment: I have an Early 2015 MBP and can control charging via the AlDente Charge Limiter app, so the part about missing hardware support can't be right. I guess it's just another thing Apple chose to exclude to make you buy something new.